# Script para trocar string de lugar com outra string

Tags: script, bash, unix

Tenho o arquivo `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` que possuem tais interfaces:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="1c:af:f7:e7:a4:3c", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="78:e3:b5:43:47:ad", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"
```

Quero substituir a `eth0` com a `eth1` e vice versa, tentei fazer com o comando sed sem sucesso:

```
sed -i 's|eth0|eth1|g'
```

ele troca o `eth0` por `eth1` obviamente mas agora tenho 2 interfaces `eth1`.

Queria um comando que "troca-se" as Strings de lugar, pra ficar com esse resultado:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="1c:af:f7:e7:a4:3c", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="78:e3:b5:43:47:ad", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
```

Comment: Você sempre vai ter somente duas linhas?

Comment: não.. foi só de exemplo mesmo...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não pode mudar A com B em una etapa. Precisa usar um valor temporário:

```
A  -> XX
B  -> A
XX -> B
```

Neste caso:

```
sed -e 's/eth0/ethXX/g' -e 's/eth1/eth0/g' -e 's/ethXX/eth1/g'
```

Retorna:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="1c:af:f7:e7:a4:3c", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="78:e3:b5:43:47:ad", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
```

Comment: hmm entendi, obrigado pela resposta! achei também esse tópico aqui http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23758321/how-to-swap-two-strings-in-file-using-bash que faz o mesmo efeito com o comando sed e perl .